# Cloning production site down to local?

Tags: localhost, testing, staging

I've been using WordPress for awhile now but one problem I'm constantly facing is creating a local clone of a production site so I can test changes/updates.

My current process goes something like this...

- Run XAMPP Server
- Download the site files (Filzilla)
- Download the database (phpMyAdmin)
- Create a local database (phpMyAdmin)
- Copy site files into XAMPP
- Import database
- Update WP hostname, settings, etc

My question is simple.  **Is it possible to automate this entire process?**  If not, what can be automated to make this less time consuming?

I've kinda looked into Docker but it seems confusing and I don't know that it helps with most of these steps.  I know there are plugins that can create backups of the site but again that only automates a couple steps. I'm pretty sure WP CLI can clone a site but I'm not sure if it can clone a remote site down to local.  A solution using WP CLI would be great.

There has to be a better process than I'm doing now :(

Answer (score 0):

It can absolutely be done using WP-Cli.

Do you have SSH access to  the remote server/site? If so, I am happy to show you a process I’ve cooked up using rsync as well as  just some standard SQL for the database. That’s my preferred way to do it at the moment.

Comment: Yes, show me please :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a number of ways to automate the process of moving sites between local, dev and production.

The first is a plugin by Delicious Brains called [WP Migrated DB Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/). The basic free plugin will move DBs between WP installs. But the add-ons really supercharge it and allow you to move images, themes and plugins, and there's a multi-site add on as well. It's one of my most cherished tools, and it makes things SO much easier.

The second tool is [Local by Flywheel](https://localwp.com/). This is another method for all-in-one WP push/pull. This tool was purchased by Flywheel who were then purchased again, so it's getting a lot of attention and has recently been significantly upgraded. I haven't used the upgraded version, but the version I have used made it VERY simple to move sites between hosts.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will look into these.